# I need to change class css with onclick in JS

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have an html like this:

```
<span class="one"> little bird is </span> <span class="two"> blue </span>
<span class="one"> little lion is </span> <span class="two"> yellow</span>
.
.
.
```

I want to click on class two (blue, yellow etc) and automatically the css display option from class one change from inline to none and when I click back the "color" to change again from none to inline.

I also want to change it individually, so when I click on blue I want to hide the "little bird is" only, when I click yellow , the little lion and so on
and when I click again the color to change back from hide to inline etc.

edit: I've found how to do it, and I've posted in answers in case anyone wants to know

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. If you have better answers let me know

```js
$('.two').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".one").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a"><a class="one hidden">little bird is </a><a href="#" class="two"> blue </a></div>



<div class="a"><a class="one hidden">little lion is </a><a href="#" class="two"> yellow</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```css
.hidden.one {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.two');

colors.forEach(color => color.addEventListener('click', e => {
  color.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
}));
```